# Catching errors while mapping a solver over a list of parameters

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, error-tracking

Perhaps this question has a simple answer, I'm sorry but I unable to get my head around it. Here's a minimal description of my issue.

I have a an equation of the form `eq = expr == 0`, where `expr` is a very complicated function of the symbols `x` and `y`.

I wish to find the roots of the equation for various values of `y`. Thus I defined the function:

```
f = Function[z, {z, x /. FindRoot[eq /. y -> z, {x, 0}]}]
```

I then define a grid:

```
 grid = Range[ymin, ymax]
```

and map over it:

```
res = Map[f, grid]
```

Apparently my equation is quite hard to solve as I get:

[image: error message]

After playing with it changes to the options of `FindRoot` such as: adding more iterations, change of method, changing working precision, etc., doesn't help me.

Thus what I would like is to be able to figure out how bad am I doing.
My issues are:

1. I don't know how many times did the execution occur as after a certain amount of times it suppresses the alerts
2. I don't know if the issues are within a certain domain, in which case I'll know I have a domain where I can't solve my equation. On the other hand maybe the points where I have my issues are sparse in which case maybe I may just ignore them?

In short I would like to add to my code (or have a separate code running over the same grid) some sort of error handler which would do one of two things:

1. Count exceptions and give me a tally. Preferably it should also defer between different exceptions as `FindRoot` can throw other exceptions as well.
2. An even better option is to return a array of exceptions and grid values, in the form:
   `{{excep1, GridVal1},{excep2, GridVal2},{excep3, GridVal3},{excep4,GridVal4}}`

I didn't post any attempt as I don't even know how to start. Complete solutions, as well as general directions will be most welcome.

#### Update

I still haven't solved my issue. However I gained some intuition regarding my problem. The solution my equation is discontinuous.
In a region around the discontinuity I have big oscillations. I could in principle be satisfied with with a solution only within a bounded domain. However, my actual problem involves several equations with several variables, so I'll need this sort of error handler to define the feasible domain.

Comment: `eq = expr == 0` gives `eq` a boolean value, i.e. `True` or `False`. Mathematica can't find a root of that. Replace `eq` with `expr` inside your `FindRoot` and that may solve the issue.

Comment: of course it can, and to works perfectly except in the region where the solution isn't continuous

Comment: Okay yes, if `expr==0` remains unevaluated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to use [`Check`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Check.html), so that when there's a message generated, an appropriate alternative result is returned. I chose [`Nothing`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nothing.html) so those results would be simply omitted, with a silly strawman version of `f`:

```
f = Function[z, {z, x /. FindRoot[Abs[Sin[x]] == z, {x, 0}]}];

Quiet[Map[Check[f[#], Nothing] &, Range[-0.5, 1.5, 0.1]]]

(* {{0., 0.}, {0.1, 0.100167}, {0.2, 0.201358}, {0.3, 0.304693}, 
    {0.4, 0.411517}, {0.5, 0.523599}, {0.6, 0.643501}, {0.7, 0.775397}, 
    {0.8, 0.927295}, {0.9, 1.11977}, {1., 1.5708}} *)
```

I wrapped the whole thing in [`Quiet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quiet.html) do avoid a bunch of annoying error messages I knew I was going to get anyway.

**EDIT**: I don't know a completely reliable way to capture the generated messages (this is a mild annoyance I've encountered repeatedly over the years), but you can hack something together using [`$MessageList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$MessageList.html), like this:

```
Map[Quiet@Check[f[#], $MessageList] &, 
 Range[-0.5, 1.5, 0.1]]
(* {{FindRoot::lstol},{FindRoot::lstol},{FindRoot::lstol},{FindRoot::lstol}, 
    {FindRoot::lstol},{0.,0.},{0.1,0.100167},{0.2,0.201358},{0.3,0.304693},  
    {0.4,0.411517},{0.5,0.523599},{0.6,0.643501},{0.7,0.775397},
    {0.8,0.927295},{0.9,1.11977},{1.,1.5708},{FindRoot::lstol},
    {FindRoot::lstol},{FindRoot::lstol},{FindRoot::lstol},
    {FindRoot::lstol}} *)
```

As you see, this gets the name of the message, but not the full body. It's more common to use a sentinel value like `$Failed` or something with head `Failure`, though. The `Quiet` is kind of obligatory here or otherwise you'll get the list of all messages generated during the whole computation, and the `General::stop` message may come up spoiling everything.

Comment: Thanks, this is great. I there way for me the change alternate behaviour (which you set to `Nothing` in your example), to the body of the warning?